# JavaScript anonymous function simulating arithmetic in lambda calculus, result returns `undefined`

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, lambda-calculus

I was intended to use javascript closure to simulate basic arithmetic in lambda calculus, to define `3 = 1 + 2`
like this:

```
0 := λf.λx.x
1 := λf.λx.f x
2 := λf.λx.f (f x)
3 := λf.λx.f (f (f x))
```

It should print three times `hello world`, now it prints once `hello world` and twice `undefined`. Could someone help to explain why this happened and what's wrong about my code? Thanks in advance.

```js
var zero = function(f) {
  return function(x) {
    return x;
  };
};

var one = function(f) {
  return function(x) {
    return f(x);
  };
};

function add(n, m) {
  return function(f) {
    return function(x) {
      return n(f)(m(f)(x));
    };
  };
}

// test, define number two and number three in lambda calculus
var two = add(one, one);
var three = add(one, two);

// function f is to console.log
var print3times = three(value => console.log(value));
print3times("hello world")
// return:
// hello world
// undefined
// undefined
```

Comment: `console.log` returns `undefined`. In `n(f)(m(f)(x))`, the inner part, `m(f)(x)`, will be a `console.log` at some point. That will result in `n(f)(undefined)` at the end, which in turn will cause `console.log(undefined)`. Even though it's a bit messy, do basic substitutions, and see, what the entire thing is.

Comment: Accordingly, this would do the three logs: `print3times = three(value => { console.log(value); return value; });`, but i am unsure what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Use this handy `log` fn: `const log = x => (console.log(x), x)`. This will log its argument, then return the argument. It's basically a mashup of `identity` and `console.log`.

Comment: Also, if you're running in an environment that supports ES6 features, arrow functions and `const` rather than `var` would be my preference for this sort of exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```js
var log = function(x) {
  console.log(x)
  return x
}

var zero = function(f) {
  return function(x) {
    return x;
  };
};

var one = function(f) {
  return function(x) {
    return f(x);
  };
};

function add(n, m) {
  return function(f) {
    return function(x) {
      return n(f)(m(f)(x));
    };
  };
}

// test, define number two and number three in lambda calculus
var two = add(one, one);
var three = add(one, two);

// function f is to console.log
var print3times = three(log);
print3times("hello world")
```

Here's an ES6 translation with a few bonus features for fun:

```js
const log = x => (console.log(x), x)

const identity = x => x
const compose = f => g => x => f(g(x))

const zero = f => identity

const one = f => x => f(x)

// I took the liberty of currying add
const add = n => m => f => x => n(f)(m(f)(x))

// test, define number two and number three in lambda calculus
const addOne = add(one)
const two = addOne(one)
const three = addOne(two)
const four = compose(addOne)(addOne)(two)

// function f is to console.log
const print3times = three(log)
print3times("hello world")

four(log)('hi X 4')
```

Also, you may find these two youtube videos entitled "A Flock of Functions: Combinators, Lambda Calculus, & Church Encodings in JS" informative: [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VQ382QG-y4), [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAnLQ9jwN-E).

Answer (score 1):

The point is that m(f)(x) in n(f)(m(f)(x)) returns undefined, since it is a console.log. Then it runs it first (and prints 'hello world'), but when running n(f) on it, it prints the result of m(f)(x): undefined.
As stated by ASDFGerte, if you add a 'return value;' to it. It will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that `three(value => console.log(value))` will do this:

```
function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value);
}
```

But it doesn't. It will actually do this:

```
function(value) {
    console.log(console.log(console.log(value)));
}
```

In other words, your lambda calculus combinators are all fine; you're just using them wrong.